# Awesome API for getting wind data?

Tags: api, weather

Looking for a good API for getting wind data for a location, whats the best free one out there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with this one

http://openweathermap.org/API

You can also fetch info from the Yahoo weather API or request a Wunderground APi too.